# Vba open files without extension from folder and save as different format

Tags: file, vba, excel, type-conversion

I am trying write a macro to get every file in a folder to open and then save as an xlsx file. The files I am working with don't have a file extension, the data is tab delimited and opens fine manually. I have this code to open every file in a folder, however I haven't been able to get it to open files without a file extension.

```
Sub Open_All_Files()
Dim oWbk As Workbook
Dim sFil As String
Dim sPath As String

sPath = "E:\Macro" 'location of files
ChDir sPath
sFil = Dir("*.xlsx") 'change or add formats
Do While sFil <> "" 
Set oWbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFil) 'opens the file

'Code to save as different file extension would go here

oWbk.Close True 'close the workbook, saving changes
sFil = Dir
Loop ' End of LOOP
End Sub
```

I also don't know how to get each file to save as an xlsx file.

I'm completely new to vba so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is the code you are looking for:

```
Sub Open_All_Files()
   Dim oWbk As Workbook
   Dim sFil As String
   Dim sPath As String

   sPath = "E:\Macro" 'location of files
   ChDrive "E" '-> if E is different than the current drive (if you didn't change it before, it is the drive where Office is installed)
   ChDir sPath
   sFil = Dir("*.*") 'change or add formats
   Do While (sFil <> ""  And InStr(sFil, ".") = 0)
      NewFileName = sPath & "\" & sFil & ".xlsx"

      On Error Resume Next
      Name sFil As NewFileName 'Add extension to file

      Set oWbk = Workbooks.Open(NewFileName) 'Open file as XLSX

      'Do anything with the workbook

      oWbk.Close True 'close the workbook, saving changes

      sFil = Dir("*.*")
   Loop ' End of LOOP
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this but it isn't working. It doesn't work when I try to use it to change .xlsx files to .xls so I don't think its just a problem with the files having no extension.

Comment: what you mean with "doesn't work"? This code should be fine. Could you please tell me what error you get or how are you using it exactly? I understand that all the files without extension are inside the folder "E:\Macro". Could you please do a step by step execution, see the values taken by each variable and telling me what  are those?

Comment: Bear in mind that it does not look for xls files, just for files with no extension. If you want to look for xls files you should convert Dir("*.*") into Dir("*.xls") and remove the And InStr(sFil, ".") = 0 bit

Comment: Let's do things step by step to avoid any misunderstanding. The code above looks for all the files WITHOUT EXTENSION in the folder "E:\Macro"; for each of them, it adds the extension (xlsx) and opens them. If this is exactly what you want, be more detailed in your proceeding because this code is fine and you should be doing something wrong. If this is not exactly what you want, please tell me what it is and I will adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is what I want it to do. When I run the macro nothing happens, there is no change to the files without extension and no error message. Thank you for your help

Comment: The best thing to understand what is happening is running the macro step-by-step. Open the code an set a break point on sFil = Dir("*.*"). Execute the macro. When it reaches the break point, press F8 and see what it does (if you put the mouse over any variable you would see the values it takes). Please, tell me what happens: does it go through the loop or skips it directly?

Comment: sPath gives the correct folder, but sFil gives the name of a file that isn't in the folder, its on a different disk drive completely. It also skips the loop.

Comment: Here you have some help to fix your problem: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=60316

Comment: I have updated the code with the suggestion in the aforementioned link. Apparently Dir does not work when using a different drive; I wasn't aware of this, sorry. Please, test the new version and let me know if it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I've now got it to open the first file and save as an xlsx but it doesn't move onto the next file, it gets stuck in an infinite loop on the first file.

Comment: This does not happen on my computer. I am not sure if this problem is related to the different-drive issue. This is a normal loop through the files in the folder under certain conditions which shouldn't provoke an endless loop. You can do some tests to come up with the best configuration; for example: use the Office drive (C y guess); have two loops (one for changing the names, until line NewFileName = sPath & "\" & sFil & ".xlsx" included; and another one to open the xlsx files); and, in general, make it as simple and one-action-at-the-time as possible. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.). The point here is not delivering a for-sure-working-code under any situation and a permanent support. This is just to give you some insight into the problem and allow you to write a code yourself. The question of how to deal with files without extension has been answered. Also why Dir does not work on a different drive.  I hope that you will understand my position: you have enough info to deal with your problems by your own (or to post a new question per each problem you have). Try to understand everything properly and come up with the most adequate solution for you.

Comment: PS: I didn't even create this code (I wouldn't have done it in such a way). I have just corrected yours.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I've finally got it! It was missing the sFil = Dir at the end

Comment: You are right. Sorry but I don't like too much this constant asking and complaining about many details when someone intends to help you with a especific issue. If I build the code myself it would work for sure; if I correct others' code, I focus on the specific problems (in this case, reading an Excel file without extension) and assume that all the other parts work fine. That's why it is a bit annoying when you keep asking for problems present in your code because of what you wrote there (which wasn't part of your answer). Anyway... the important thing is the result: enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is only looking for files that already have the .xlsx extension. Try `Dir('*')`.

If you are just renaming the files then I wouldn't attempt to open them. I would use `FileCopy`

```
FileCopy source, destination
```

where source and destination are both strings. For example, the following worked for me (on Windows XP):

```
    FileCopy "testthis", "testthis.xlsx"
```

You could then use `Kill` to delete the old file

```
Kill pathname
```

Comment: This does create a new file with the correct name, but excel throws up the error "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid". I think this might be because when I open the files manually I have to go through a couple of dialog boxes telling excel how the data is delimited. Maybe I need to have each file opened in order to save them as the new format?